# Codeigniter: Return view with header and footer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just a beginner and just want to ask if how can I also return the header and footer template? The template works, but not the animation and the function. Below is the code. I'm using codeigniter 4.

```
echo view('templates/header');
return view('pages/stud-home', $data);
echo view('templates/footer');
```

Comment: Where your animation scripts belongs? May help this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html

Comment: You should not before echoing another view. In your code, the footer won't get rendered

Comment: I already fix it! Thanks! I used this: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-71825.html

Answer (score 0):

```
## This is the simple way to view header and footer ##



public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('pages/stud-home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```